# Not able to open port on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, port, ufw

```
root@server:~# ufw allow 83973/tcp
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
root@server:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
root@server:~# sudo ufw enable
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup

root@server:~# sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
83973                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
83973/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
83973 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
83973/tcp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

root@server:~#
```

I am trying to add listening port 83973 but its not working. 
Please advise

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but TCP ports higher than 65535 would not be possible, since they would overflow the 16 bits dedicated to the port in the protocol.